# I want to insert data from a cursor into an object table, but I can't

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE O_T_emplo AS OBJECT (
L_o_first_name VARCHAR2(30),
L_o_last_name  VARCHAR2(30),
L_o_depar      NUMBER,
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION O_T_emplo(
L_o_first_name VARCHAR2(30),
L_o_last_name  VARCHAR2(30),
L_o_depar      NUMBER)
RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY O_T_emplo IS
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION O_T_emplo(
L_o_first_name VARCHAR2(30),
L_o_last_name  VARCHAR2(30),
L_o_depar      NUMBER
) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
BEGIN
SELF.L_o_first_name := L_o_first_name;
SELF.L_o_last_name  := L_o_last_name;
self.L_o_depar      := L_o_depar;
RETURN;
END;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_obj AS TABLE OF O_T_emplo;
/
```

Use it plsql:

```
DECLARE
  tab_emps tab_obj;
  info_emps O_T_emplo;
  CURSOR C_infos IS 
    SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, e.department_id 
    FROM employees e;
  infos C_infos%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  tab_emps := tab_obj();
  OPEN C_infos;
  LOOP
    FETCH C_infos INTO infos;
    info_emps := O_T_emplo(infos.first_name, infos.last_name, infos.department_id);
    tab_emps.extend();
    tab_emps(tab_emps.LAST) := info_emps;
    EXIT WHEN C_infos%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;  
  CLOSE C_infos;
END;
/
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why can't you? Do get an error?

Comment: "but I can't" isn't very helpful; why can't you? Do you get an error, or wrong results, or something else? Please edit your question to explain the problem, including the full text of any error you get.

Comment: Sorry, the error is: type "HR.O_T_EMPLO" HAS ERROS
PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "HR.O_T_EMPLO"
at line 12.
Thanks

Comment: You don't need the `CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION` when the signature of this function is the same as the object itself.

Comment: Just a note, you can also use `BULK COLLECT INTO info_emps`, should be much faster than adding the records one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the type, remove the length from `VARCHAR2` data types in the signature of the constructor in the declaration and the body.
- In the PL/SQL block, change the order in the loop so you `EXIT` immediately after the `FETCH`; if you do it the other way round then the final row of the cursor will be inserted twice.
- Optionally, you can remove the `info_emps` intermediate variable.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE O_T_emplo AS OBJECT (
  L_o_first_name VARCHAR2(30),
  L_o_last_name  VARCHAR2(30),
  L_o_depar      NUMBER,

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION O_T_emplo(
    L_o_first_name VARCHAR2,
    L_o_last_name  VARCHAR2,
    L_o_depar      NUMBER
  ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY O_T_emplo IS
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION O_T_emplo(
    L_o_first_name VARCHAR2,
    L_o_last_name  VARCHAR2,
    L_o_depar      NUMBER
  ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.L_o_first_name := L_o_first_name;
    SELF.L_o_last_name  := L_o_last_name;
    self.L_o_depar      := L_o_depar;
    RETURN;
  END;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_obj AS TABLE OF O_T_emplo;
/
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  tab_emps tab_obj;
  CURSOR C_infos IS SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, e.department_id FROM employees e;
  infos C_infos%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  tab_emps := tab_obj();
  OPEN C_infos;
  LOOP
    FETCH C_infos INTO infos;
    EXIT WHEN C_infos%NOTFOUND;
    tab_emps.extend();
    tab_emps(tab_emps.LAST) := O_T_emplo(
      infos.first_name,
      infos.last_name,
      infos.department_id
    );
  END LOOP;  
  CLOSE C_infos;
  
  FOR i IN 1 .. tab_emps.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      tab_emps(i).l_o_first_name || ', ' ||
      tab_emps(i).l_o_last_name || ', ' ||
      tab_emps(i).l_o_depar
      
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6c37bfd5c8d8eac214ea969109f2bf25)*